# CSS divs into columns and image stretch to window

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I have three columns inside a div called row and each column is in a div called third-col. I want the three columns side by side (inline) and then the next div contact to be below them. Currently all of the divs are in block one after another.

Another problem I'm having is with my home image. When the browser window is not maximized I want the image to still stretch to the bottom of the page.

```css
img {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: inline;    
}

.third-col {
  width: 30.3%;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline;
}

.col {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<img class="center" src="homepage.jpg" alt="">
<section id="skills">
  <p class="header">My Skills</p>
  <div class="skillsContainer">
    <div id="row">
      <div class="third-col"> 
        <ul>
          <li>items</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What does your `.col` represent? Do you want 3 divs inline and one under the three?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/656bhx79/ because of padding, set width of columns to slightly under 33%. Also set to inline-block (the columns) You're better off setting your image as a background image. Use cover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you background-image, you will want it to set it using CSS. This will allow it to stretch from side to side, top to bottom. Here is an example:

```css
.body { margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.full-page-image {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489914099268-1dad649f76bf?auto=format&fit=crop&w=2850&q=80);
  background-size: cover; /* THIS MAKES THE IMAGE STRETCH TO ALWAYS COVER THE PAGE */
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh; /* This is 100% of the height */
}
```

```html
<div class="full-page-image"></div>

<h1>Page content goes here</h1>
```

For the rows, I suggest using flexbox. Here is a complete guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

The idea is that each row is 100% of the witdh of the page. The content inside the row will be divided by the width you want. Here is an example:

```css
.row{
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: flex; /* Makes the sub-elements flex */
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* Forces flexbox to respect children width */
    align-items: stretch; /* Makes childs the same height */
}
.third-col{
    width: 33%;
    font-size: 16px;
    min-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="third-col">Col 1</div>
  <div class="third-col">Col 2</div>
  <div class="third-col">Col 3</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <div>Other page content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't need  to add width and height of 100% to the image size is set to cover

Comment: @RachelGallen In the question they say "I want the image to still stretch to the bottom of the page" so I assumed they wanted the image to be full page. If it's not the case, I will update my answer. Setting the background-image without height and width will make the image invisible (hiehgt / width of 0).

Comment: See fiddle. The width and height of the image are adjusted from the original size of the image (which is generally not 0px) when background size is set to cover. Fiddle is in comments.

Comment: From the example they gave, the image is before the divided content. So yes, if I place the image in CSS at the same place in the initial example, the height would be of 0. Also using width that are slightly under 33.333% isn't optimal. Flexbox is the new standard made specially for cases like this one.

Comment: when have you ever added an image that when created is 0x0?

Comment: Like here? https://jsfiddle.net/loic294/z0px9mb9/ This is an error I see all my friends do when starting to do CSS. Because an `img` tag is by default the size of the image, people expect to be the same when they use CSS (which is not the case).

Comment: there is no class or id specified in your css to go with your attributes. I asked about the size of the original image, not poor coding

Comment: True, I forgot to wrap it in a div. Fixed. And I understand your point now! Yes, you do not need height/width when applying the background to the body element. But that's not what I did. I created a container with the background image, and for that, yes the height is needed.

Comment: If you added any content, even a word, to your div, the background size would adjust to cover the content. You only need to specify a height if you want a desired minimum height. One doesn't usually create empty divs.

Comment: Yes I know that, but to always make it the full height of the page, you need to have a height.

Comment: Good night. Anyways, we have two different solutions that are perfectly valid. It all depends on what the person wanted exactly.....

Comment: The code for the background worked, however I'd like for my image to be centered based on the browser window size. Specifically I have a large image that looks great with the browser maximizes but if the browser is smaller, I'd like the center of the image to remain in the center of the page.

Comment: Add `background-position: center center;`. This centers the image vertically and horizontally. I also updated my example with this.